# using strftime for 31 december shows next year

Tags: php, timestamp, locale, strftime

Using this code,

```
   setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');
    $end_date_formatted = utf8_encode(strftime("%d %B %G", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month_end, $day_end, $year_end)));
```

strftime is not returning the right year only for Dec 31. 
it should display 31 decembre 2013, but it displays 31 decembre 2014

Comment: What values are being passed for `$day_end, $month_end, $year_end`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You <del>are</del> were using [mktime()](http://php.net/mktime) wrong. It's:

> int mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") [, int $minute = date("i") [, int
> $second = date("s") [, int **$month** = date("n") [, int **$day** = date("j")
> [, int **$year** = date("Y") [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )

... and you have:

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, $day_end, $month_end, $year_end)
```

Fixed that, you're probably hitting the issue that the [note in the `strftime()` manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#refsect1-function.strftime-notes) warns about:

> Note: %G and %V, which are based on ISO 8601:1988 week numbers can give unexpected (albeit correct) results if the numbering system is
> not thoroughly understood. See %V examples in this manual page.

31st Dec 2013 belongs to first ISO week of next year.

You probably want `%Y` instead.

Comment: This would explain it, adding anything over 12 would automatically push the year up

Comment: my bad, its mktime(0, 0, 0, $month_end, $day_end, $year_end). edited question